# Disable selected option in multiple select html

Tags: php, laravel

I want to disable all option on "MULTIPLE SELECT" that has been selected in "SELECTED" list

[image: Ilustration]

For the multiple select, I got the list from database using foreach:

```
@foreach($category as $item)
  <option value="{{$item->id}}">{{$item->name}}</option>
@endforeach
```

Is there anything I can do for this case? Should I compare the list database into the selected list database? If yes, then how?

Comment: remove selected array from select array...

Answer (score 0):

```
    @foreach($category as $item)
       <option value="{{$item->id}}" {{ in_array($selected, $item->id) ? 'disabled' :'' }}>{{$item->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
```

Where `$selected` is a simple array of already selected values that are keyed to the option ID's.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="category []" multiple="multiple">
   @foreach($category as $item)
       <option value="{{$item->id}}" {{ in_array($selected, $item->id) ? 'selected' :'' }}>{{$item->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
});
```

Hope this works